# Silex with Doctrine and PHP classes

Tags: php, class, doctrine, silex

So, I'm trying to get around in Silex. Just learn the way it works and I'm trying to use Doctrine in it. I can use it on the index.php, but I'd also like to use it in my classes. These lines are used in the normal root file (index.php):

```
$images = $app['db']->prepare("SELECT * FROM images");
$images->execute();

$images = $images->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, \AI\Models\Image::class);
```

So that would give me the ability to do something with the images. But I don't want to work this way. I'd like classes to do it all for me, so that I just script some methods which do all the hard work for me. That would let me just run one line for each Route in index.php

The problem is that I don't know how to connect with Doctrine from inside my classes. Because there is no '$app' in there. I think it would be weird to start the app inside of a class.

So let's say I wanted to create a user class. This SQL would give me all the users: "SELECT * FROM users". But how would I use Doctrine inside the User class?

```
<?php

namespace Models;

class User {

    public function find($user){
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

            $data = // RUN QUERY $SQL 
            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->all();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You might wanna look at Pimple to handle your dependency injection. http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `index.php` follow these steps.

- Create instance of the silex application:

  ```
  $app = new Silex\Application();
  $app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
  ```
- Set the database configuration:

  ```
  $config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
  $connParams = array(
      'driver'   => 'driver',
      'dbname'   => 'dbname',
      'host'     => 'host',
      'user'     => 'user',
      'password' => 'pass',
      'charset'  => 'charset',
      'port'     => 'port' 
  );
  ```
- Connect to database:

  ```
  $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connParams, $config);
  ```

Now you have different ways to make this db instance accessible throughout your app. You can whether make a global variable adding the instance in it:

```
global $dbcon;
$dbcon = $conn;
```

Or simply add it to the `$app` itself:

```
$app['dbcon'] = $conn;
```

Furthermore you might want to add a constructor to your models like this:

```
public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

Comment: Ahh So I would just give the $conn instance to the constructor?

Comment: Correct! if you use the global variable method then just pass that one in constructor; if you use the `$app` then you need to pass it from your controller while instantiating the model. Like: `$myModelIns = new MyModelName($app['dbcon']);`

Comment: Yep, I've used the last method!

Comment: Never use globals. Instead return the application object from one master configuration php file and include that file in every other file so services can be accessed through the Pimple.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to inject those instances in your controller.
I looked through the docs real quick and think I found what you need.

Here is a link to the documentation page : http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/service_controller.html.

the documentation page explains everything you need to know to get what you want to achieve.